# Django gets error when overriding save method

Tags: python, django

I overriding model's `save()` method to do some work with directory.

My overrided `save()` method looks like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    book_dir = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, self.title)

    # check that at least one file is loading
    if all([self.pdf, self.fb2, self.epub]):
        raise ValidationError("At least 1 file should be uploaded!")
    # create book's directory if it not exists
    if os.path.exists(book_dir):
        raise ValidationError("This book is already exists!")
    else:
        os.mkdir(book_dir)

    # assign uploading files storage
    for x in [self.image, self.pdf, self.fb2, self.epub]:
        x.storage = book_dir

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Everything goes well until last line. Django gives me `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'save'` error.

UPD 1:
Added full model

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Book title",
        max_length=75,
        null=False,
        unique=True,
        )
    year_pub = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name="Year published",
        null=False
        )
    image = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name="Preview image",
        null=False
        )
    pdf = models.FileField(
        verbose_name="PDF file",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[validators.validate_book_ext]
        )
    fb2 = models.FileField(
        verbose_name="FB2 file",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[validators.validate_book_ext]
        )
    epub = models.FileField(
        verbose_name="EPUB file",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[validators.validate_book_ext]
        )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        book_dir = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, self.title)

        # check that at least one file is loading
        if all([self.pdf, self.fb2, self.epub]):
            raise ValidationError("At least 1 file should be uploaded!")
        # create book's directory if it not exists
        if os.path.exists(book_dir):
            raise ValidationError("This book is already exists!")
        else:
            os.mkdir(book_dir)

        # assign uploading files storage
        for x in [self.image, self.pdf, self.fb2, self.epub]:
            x.storage = book_dir

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

UPD 2:
Added traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 606, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1634, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1522, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1561, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1088, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "C:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\djangoApp\library\models.py", line 58, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1334, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1278, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1278, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1277, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1228, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 288, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
  File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 87, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'save'
[19/Sep/2019 23:11:03] "POST /admin/library/book/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 181939
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error points to that specific line? And not to somewhere else in your code? You should be doing this in your fields' validator anyway tho.

Comment: Can you post the full class, and what you're calling .save on ?

Comment: @IşıkKaplan i passed through method with debugger from vscode. after `super().save(...)` i have nothing.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing here. Why are you assigning strings as the storage attribute for those fields? If you're trying to use a dynamic upload directory, that's not at all how to do it. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Comment: @DanielRoseman i cant do like this, because i have dinamically creating directories for each individual book. and it should be created only when book is uploading, not before.

Answer (score 0):

So, i missed 1 more method of storage to override.

Now my overwriting loop storage location works well and looks like this:

```
# rename and edit storage location of books to book_dir
for field in [self.image, self.pdf, self.fb2, self.epub]:
    field.storage.location = book_dir
```